# Скрытие файлов из просмотра кода

Tags: javascript, html, html5, браузер

возникла необходимость скрыть скрипт, используемый в сайте, но как быть, если его можно посмотреть через код элемента?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи...

Comment: А зачем его скрывать? Максимум, что вы можете сделать это искусственно усложнить код, но это не гарант безопасности от reverse engineering-а.

Comment: настроить деплой проекта таким, чтобы выкладывать js прямо в html. А чтобы полностью обезопасить себя - удалить полностью js кода, таким образом никто не узнает ваш js

Comment: если там что-то секретное - оно должно храниться на сервере. а скрыть js из браузера невозможно. это как спрашивать, как убрать из самолёта двигатели, но чтобы самолёт всё так же разгонялся и летел как раньше

Answer (score 0):

никак. Если вы это делаете для взлома или встаивания левого кода который, к примеру будет отправлять статистику или пароли на левый `url`, то всё равно его будет видно. `JS` - браузерный язык, а `DevTools` как раз и создан для того что бы смотреть, что откуда, куда идет.

Как советовали выше, можете инлайново встраивать в код страници, что б он не отображался.

Comment: Там вроде все проще, просто рандомно генерится кол-во человек в шапке которые якобы в сейчас играют.